# sending mail in php with user informations

Tags: php

hii evryone plz i need help i want to know why my code send only the attachment but not the others informations of my contact form here is my code php
here is my code the attachement is sent correctly but the other 
informations not  i dont using any framework it is just php
i use a contact form with attachement

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1); //Affichage des erreurs

//Eviter les insertions de scripts dans le cas d'un e-mail HTML
$nom = htmlentities($_POST['firstname']);
$email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
$nom=$_POST['firstname'];
//$prenom = htmlentities($_POST['prenom']);

//Verifie si le fournisseur prend en charge les r
if(preg_match("#@(hotmail|live|msn).[a-z]{2,4}$#", $email)){
$passage_ligne = "\n";
}else{
$passage_ligne = "\r\n";
 }



  $email_to = "mon adresse email"; //Destinataire
  $email_subject = "Recrutement "; //Sujet du mail
  $boundary = md5(rand()); // clé aléatoire de limite

  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 

  $headers.= "From: EA\r\n"; 
  $headers.= "Reply-To: EITA" . "\r\n";
  $headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $passage_ligne;
  $headers.= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary='.$boundary .' '. 
  $passage_ligne;


   //Pièce jointe
   if(isset($_FILES["fichier"]) && $_FILES['fichier']['name'] != ""){ 
   //Vérifie sur formulaire envoyé et que le fichier existe
    $nom_fichier = $_FILES['fichier']['name'];

   $source = $_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name'];
   $type_fichier = $_FILES['fichier']['type'];
   $taille_fichier = $_FILES['fichier']['size'];

 if($nom_fichier != ".htaccess"){ //Vérifie que ce n'est pas un .htaccess
 if($type_fichier == "image/jpeg" 
 || $type_fichier == "image/pjpeg" 
 || $type_fichier == "application/pdf"){ //Soit un jpeg soit un pdf

   if ($taille_fichier <= 2097152) { //Taille supérieure à Mo (en octets)
  $tabRemplacement = array("é"=>"e", "è"=>"e", "à"=>"a"); //Remplacement des 
  caractères spéciaux

   $handle = fopen($source, 'r'); //Ouverture du fichier
   $content = fread($handle, $taille_fichier); //Lecture du fichier
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //Encodage
    $f = fclose($handle); //Fermeture du fichier
   //$message.='--'.$passage_ligne."\r\n";
   $email_message.="Content-Type: pdf; name=".$nom_fichier."\r\n";
    $email_message.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64"."\r\n";
    $email_message.="Content-Disposition: attachment; 
   filename=".$nom_fichier."\r\n\r\n"; 
   $email_message.= 
   chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($nom_fichier)))."\r\n";

   $email_message.='--'.$passage_ligne.'--'."\r\n";
   $email_message .= $encoded_content."n"; //Pièce jointe
   //$email_message .="Hello";

 }else{
 //Message d'erreur
  $email_message .= $passage_ligne ."L'utilisateur a tenté de vous envoyer 
 une pièce jointe mais celle ci était superieure à 2Mo.". $passage_ligne;
 }
 }else{
 //Message d'erreur
 $email_message .= $passage_ligne ."L'utilisateur a tenté de vous envoyer 
  une pièce jointe mais elle n'était pas au bon format.". $passage_ligne;
 }
 }else{
 //Message d'erreur
  $email_message .= $passage_ligne ."L'utilisateur a tenté de vous envoyer 
  une pièce jointe .htaccess.". $passage_ligne;
   }
   }
  $email_message .= $passage_ligne . "--" . $boundary . "--" . 
 $passage_ligne; //Séparateur de fermeture
 $msg.=$email_message.$nom."bonjour"; 
  if(mail($email_to,$email_subject, $msg, $headers)==true){ //Envoi du mail
  header('Location: index.php'); //Redirection
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Can you try adding a few texts before you attach the file and see if that is sent?

Comment: Actualy it works but i need to recap the user information in a html mail i try to set the header to works both with html format and attachement format but it didn t works $headers.= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary='.$boundary .' '. $passage_ligne; and $headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n';